# Business service using route OSB

Tags: oracle11g, osb

I have a business services that is called using route.
When I used route option the response is different and incorrect compared to service callout. I checked in logs and the outbound, header and body are identical. The request is the same, but the response is different when using route and service callout.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The two operations have different usability in OSB. You can use routing if you intend to pass your resultant payload from one proxy to one business service (BS) for the purpose of performing the operation that the BS is designed for. In case of routing, the calling proxy does not expect or wait for a successful response from the BS. It is like fire and forget

But service callout is used where I am expecting a response from the business service for example the BS sends a SOAP query and gets a response and that response is received in the proxy service. In this case, I intend to use the response payload for further decision making and processing activities.For example you want to pass the `<creditCardNumber/>` in the request and in the response you are looking for the `<cardStatus/>` tag value whether it is ACTIVE or INACTIVE.

Thus in the later case it is not fire and forget and we are interested in the response and we are using Service Callout, not Route.

Comment: To add further, in case of service callout, the response is the actual response payload but for route, only the payloads in the overall flow of operation can be tracked but it is not what we call any actual response payload